# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el mensaje de la advertencia de Bloq Mayús en un TextBox de contraseña?, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2010

Al momento del usuario escribir su contraseña si activa la tecla de <kbd>Bloq Mayús</kbd> (<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>) le muestra la advertencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el evento `KeyDown` del `textbox` de contraseña puedo utilizar esto para detectarla:

```
if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
```

O más amplio hacer esto:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

public void CheckKeyState()
{
   if ((GetKeyState(0x14) & 0x0001)!=0)
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock ON!");
   else
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock OFF!");
}

 private void txt_clave_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     CheckKeyState();
 }
```

**Existe alguna manera de personalizar el mensaje que muestra la advertencia?**

Para cambiarlo a otro idioma, agregar palabras o quitar palabras.